# If statements and vertical buttons

Tags: java, if-statement, jpanel, joptionpane, jdialog

I am making a fighting game and the player will choose its class. How do I say If (Player chooses Warrior) then (blah) with my code?

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonTest {
static JDialog dialog;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDialog dialog = null;
    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
    optionPane.setMessage("Choose Your Class!");
    optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    String[] buttonTxt = {"Warrior","Battlemage","Tank","Archer","Kitty"};
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[buttonTxt.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonTxt.length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i] = new JButton(buttonTxt[i]);
        panel.add(buttons[i]);
    }
    optionPane.setOptionType(JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
    optionPane.add(panel);
    dialog = optionPane.createDialog(null, "Icon/Text Button");
    dialog.setVisible(true);

 }

}
```

Comment: What is actually your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use actionperformed event for all the buttons.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonTxt.length; i++){
        buttons[i] = new JButton(buttonTxt[i]);
        buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                onClickButton(buttonTxt[i]);
            }
        });
        panel.add(buttons[i]);
    }
```

Make **buttonTxt** a final variable.
Then you can write your if statement inside **onClickButton()**

```
private void onClickButton(String buttonText){
    if(buttonText.equals("Warrior")){
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```